# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input when receiving json from php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to display some data from MySQL database in a table using JQUERY , so I wrote this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#a1<?=$com->code_fournisseur?>").click(function () {
        $("#tab1<?=$com->code_fournisseur?>").show();
        $("#tab2<?=$com->code_fournisseur?>").hide();
        $("#tab3<?=$com->code_fournisseur?>").hide();
        $("#tab4<?=$com->code_fournisseur?>").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            url: 'fournisseur.php',
            data: {'id_f': <?=$com->code_fournisseur?> , 'type': 'article_f'},
            success: function (response) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    $("#tab1<?=$com->code_fournisseur?>").html(response[i]["id_article_interne"]);
                    // just to see some result 
                }


            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) ; 
                //alert();
                console.log(xhr.responseText + " " + error);
                //alert(error);
            }

        });

    });
```

then , this PHP receive the request  :

```
if($_POST["type"] == 'article_f'){
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT fourn_code,code_article,designation,id_article_interne,prix , remise,taux_tva,disponible,qte_cdes 
            FROM `adm_fourn_articles` WHERE fourn_code = '".$_POST["id_f"]."'" ;
        $articles = $db->executeQuery($sql) ;
        foreach ($articles as $article) {
            # code...
            $article->id_article_interne = GetChamp("article","id_article",$article->id_article_interne,"adm_helpdesk_articles") ;

        }
        $json = json_encode($articles);
        echo $json ; }
    catch(PDOException $Exception){
        echo  $Exception->getMessage( ) ;
    }
}
```

but I got this error Message  :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I did a test to see if my php is incorrect  : it gives me this JSON :

```
[{
    "fourn_code": "F00141",
    "code_article": "1",
    "designation": "crayon",
    "id_article_interne": "10 Kgs de ciments",
    "prix": "0.00",
    "remise": "0.00",
    "taux_tva": "10.00",
    "disponible": "Disponible",
    "qte_cdes": "0.00"
}, {
    "fourn_code": "F00141",
    "code_article": "mg",
    "designation": "JEUX",
    "id_article_interne": "jeux educatifs pratique \"le corps humain\"",
    "prix": "6000.00",
    "remise": "0.00",
    "taux_tva": "20.00",
    "disponible": "Disponible",
    "qte_cdes": "0.00"
}]
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Format your post correctly.

Comment: If you somehow end up in the `catch` condition, you're not returning JSON, just an error, and your ajax request will fail as it's not receiving valid JSON

Comment: check output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($articles);` before `json_encode()` and see what is coming

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using PDO, take advantage of [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [bindparam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindvalue](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: this is what i got from print_r($articles):
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fourn_code] => F00141 [code_article] => 1 [designation] => crayon [id_article_interne] => 10 Kgs de ciments [prix] => 0.00 [remise] => 0.00 [taux_tva] => 10.00 [disponible] => Disponible [qte_cdes] => 0.00 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [fourn_code] => F00141 [code_article] => mg [designation] => JEUX [id_article_interne] => jeux educatifs pratique "le corps humain" [prix] => 6000.00 [remise] => 0.00 [taux_tva] => 20.00 [disponible] => Disponible [qte_cdes] => 0.00 ) )